# HasOne Relationship Differences between v5.5 and v5.6 - no longer the same?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a Person model with demogographic information, Orgs model with organization information and an OrgPerson model that is effectively a pivot table with additional fields.  I've crated OrgPerson to extend Model instead of Pivot because it worked better with my setup.

```
--- Edit: table structures ---
Table: person (Model: Person)
    PK: personID
        (other demographic fields)
        defaultOrgID (FK -> orgID) // the org that will be displayed/referenced by default 
                                   // changeable by user with multiple orgs

Table: organization (Model: Org)
    PK: orgID
        (other org-demographic fields)

Table: org-person (Model: OrgPerson -- functionally a pivot table)
    PK: personID, orgID
        (other combo-demographic fields for the person with respect to the org)

--- End of table structures edit ---
```

I acknowledge that the OrgPerson model is the capture of a many-to-many relationship.  However, I need to be able to grab the "combo-demographic" data (stored in the OrgPerson record) for the person related to the defaultOrgID.

Because a Person can belong to multiple Orgs, I want the orgperson record for $this person but for the "default" Org as stored in $person->defaultOrgID.

My Person model had the following relation defined in v5.5 and it returned what I wanted via $person->load('orgperson') or via eager loading.

```
public function orgperson()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrgPerson::class, 'personID', 'personID')
        ->where('orgID', $this->defaultOrgID);
}
```

Running code like:

```
$person = Person::find(x);
$person->load('orgperson')
```

Returns a Person model with a non-null orgperson model in the relationships list.

After upgrading to v5.6 and performing some testing, I'm finding that this relation is not populating.  I haven't gotten it to populate in any of my testing and I cannot find any reason why it would be different.

Comment: does the OrgPerson model have protected $table = 'mytable'; and  protected $primaryKey = 'personID'; ?

Comment: Yes to both $primaryKey and $table

Comment: can you remove the ->where('orgID', $this->defaultOrgID); and check if it works ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did try that to make sure things were working.  It returns one of the relation and is correct when person is connected to only 1 org via 1 orgperson record.  However, in the event there are multiple orgs to which a person is connected, I would need  person->orgperson to return the correct one. 

I tested this on a person with multiple org & orgperson records and what is returned cannot be guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: try 'App\OrgPerson' instead of OrgPerson::class you are trying to load a relation while the object is not yet loaded though it should be because you already ran the query for the person its acting funky what is the defaultOrgID ? is it the person id ?

Comment: defaultOrgID is an orgID (FK to org table) and intermediate key (with personID) in orgperson (pivot) table.  Adding "App\" to the OrgPerson::class in the relation flags as an error (and unnecessary when adding a use statement in the Person model.  In the code trying to instantiate it, through Person, it wouldn't make sense (to me at least) to change that to OrgPerson because I need the Person record with the OrgPerson relation.  Make sense?

Comment: ok let me get list all the table structures because you seem to have many to many no one to many

Comment: for now i think its not working like past because there is something not right in the migrations cause foreign referencing but the structure i don't understand please post the migrations and all the relations

Comment: I will add table details (I have no migration files) to the original original post in ~3 hours.  I’m unable to do so at the moment.

Comment: i read the table details shouldn't it be like this  $this->hasOne(OrgPerson::class, 'defaultOrgID', 'personID') ? like a normal hasOne relation it will change depending on defaultOrgID just like any changing relation

Comment: If I understand how the relation should work, the FK should be a reference to the PK in the corresponding tables.   Person has a personID and defaultOrgID is the FK to the org table.  If my current code was a hasMany instead of hasOne, I'd get a collection of orgperson records based on how it's setup (personID as FK to personID as PK).  But, I want to figure out how to just get the 1 record that is connected to $this->personID with the correct orgID (as stored in defaultOrgID).  Make sense?

Comment: defaultOrgID is foreign key that references the id on the pivot table return $this->hasOne(OrgPerson::class, 'defaultOrgID', 'personID'); try this if the defaultOrgID value is already in the table it should work defaultOrgID will be the orgperson normal id not the person or the company andit will map back through the personID

Comment: Your suggestion causes the following error:   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'org-person.defaultOrgID' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `org-person` where `org-person`.`defaultOrgID` in (1755) and `org-person`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: thats migrations then you need to add foriegn('defaultOrgID)->refrences('id')->on('org-person');

Comment: Because defaultOrgID is on the person table, I reversed the parameters to the hasOne statement as follows (to stop the error):  return $this->hasOne(OrgPerson::class, 'orgID', 'defaultOrgID');  That statement no longer causes a SQL error BUT, it's just pulling the first orgperson record it finds that matches the orgID as stored in defaultOrgID.  The problem with this suggestion is that a where clause is required because it's both the personID and orgID that need to be found in order to be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193047/discussion-between-phil-and-ahmed-aboud).

Comment: @AhmedAboud if you submit as an answer your suggestion to give the OrgPerson model its own key and reference it from Person, I'll accept it as an answer as that has been easy to implement and didn't cause any adverse, unforeseen, issues.  :-)   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a migration to give orgperson table a primary key

```
Schema::table('orgperson', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});
```

so you can do something like this

```
public function orgperson()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrgPerson::class, 'defaultOrgID', 'personID')
}
```